# QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'QList<char>' for property 'className::pointType''

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

The problem is that `char` is NOT "my" type. It is a key word in C and C++.

I wrote this:

`Q_PROPERTY (QList<char> pointType     READ pointType     WRITE setPointType     NOTIFY pointTypeChanged)`

and I get that error when I access it in QML. Yes, I have used `qmlRegisterType` for registering my class in `main.cpp`.

I have used other objects too like `int` and `QList`, but the error occurs only for `char`.

Comment: and if you used a `QChar`?

Comment: AH! @Theolodis I didn't try that! Why would char not work but when int works?

Comment: Why is something called `pointType` a `char`? And so it works if you just switch it to be list of `int`?

Comment: @hyde `pointType` will hold the data of type char. Anything other than char works e.g. QList, int, QString etc.